# Unable to extract an rar archive

Tags: 14.04, archive, rar

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and I want to decompress a 500 MB `rar` archive. I have installed the most recent version of `rar` and `unrar` from the terminal.

When I go to extract the contents from the archive the Archive Manager extracts them, but it takes a little while and at the end I get a message that says:

> produced an error when extracting the file

and it gives me only the option of closing the Archive Manager. I'm desperate because I downloaded the same GTA San Andreas archive of different videos three times, and it always tells me the same thing which I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04 I use rar from command line to solve this problem with the Archive Manager, which is probably bound to some tricky-faulty rar files. Although most of the times, not all are unzipped. Some of the zipped files return error.